# GMock: Match the address of EXPECT_CALL parameter

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

Is there a way to match the address of a given parameter in an `EXPECT_CALL`?

I have code like the following:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock1, GetTheData()).WillOnce(Return(theData));
EXPECT_CALL(mock2, SetTheData(_)); // How to check the parameter is the same object as the one returned by GetTheData

// the following was tried but does not work
EXPECT_CALL(mock2, SetTheData(_)).WillOnce([&theData](auto param){ EXPECT_EQ(&theData, param) })
```

But because the SetTheData function takes its  argument by value, the address is different. So I would need to find a way to get the object, before it was passed to the SetTheData function.

I tried some stuff with matches, but that did not seem to work either.

Is this possible at all? If so, how? And if not, why not?

EDIT:

As requested here is a more complete example to give more context.

```
struct TheData
{
  // some stl containers
  std::unordered_map<int, std::array<std::byte, 16>> mapToArrays;
  std::unordered_map<int, long long> mapToInts;
}

class IDataFetcher
{
public:
  virtual TheData GetTheData() = 0;
}

class IDataReceiver
{
public:
  virtual void SetTheData(TheData theData) = 0;
}

class DataFetcherMock : public IDataFetcher
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(TheData, GetTheData, (), (override));
}

class DataReceiverMock
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD(void, SetTheData, (TheData), (override));
}

class Sut
{
public:
  Sut(std::unique_ptr<IDataFetcher> fetcher, std::unique_ptr<IDataReceiver> receiver)

  void DoTheThing()
  {
    mReceiver->SetTheData(mFetcher->GetTheData());
  }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<IDataFetcher> mFetcher;
  std::unique_ptr<IDataReceiver> mReceiver;
}


TEST(TestFoo, TestGroupFoo)
{
  auto fetcherMock = std::make_unique<DataFetcherMock>();
  auto receiverMock = std::make_unique<DataReceiverMock>();

  EXPECT_CALL(*fetcherMock, GetTheData()).WillOnce(Return(theData));
  EXPECT_CALL(*receiverMock, SetTheData(_)); // Here I want to check the objects are the same

  Sut sut(std::move(fetcherMock), std::move(receiverMock));

  sut.DoTheThing();
}
```

Comment: If `SetTheData` takes it's argument by value, it is generally assumed that a copy is stored internally instead of the same pointer.  Hence, `GetTheData` returns a copy, not the pointer.  Can you show the original declarations of `GetTheData` and `SetTheData` and something that resembles the type declaration of `theData` - that might clear up the misunderstanding.  Or as we say around here, a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know your use case, but it seems to me that you shouldn't check if this is exactly the same object, but rather if it equal to / contains the same set of of values as the object returned by `mock1`. This would be resolved using a matcher or equality operator.

Comment: @selbie I edited my question and gave a more elaborate example. Sorry for the incomplete question.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes right, my thought was that in this test I do not care about the data itself in the struct, but only that the struct obtained by the Fetcher is the same as the one given to the Receiver. And my thought was that it might be simpler to just check the address.

Comment: Based on the function signatures, there's no way you should expect that `GetTheData` would return the same object at the same address as what was passed to `SetTheData`.  And if you are trying to validate if the `SetTheData` gets the same address as what was returned from `GetTheData`, that won't work either.  The function signature implies copies of `theData` are happening all over the place.

Comment: @selbie I guess a workaround for the problem with the getter would be to use `Return(ByRef(theData))`, right? So the problem still is only with using the Setter

Comment: You are better off modifying your test to check for object equality than attempting to test the addresses.  That is, write a test function that compares the contents of two instances `theData` rather than trying to doing all this reference/address comparision stuff

Comment: @selbie Jup, that's pretty much the conclusion I have come to now aswell. I will do that. So to answer the question. It is not possible, because the mock object internally only stores a copy and not the original object that was passed to it.

Comment: And thank you, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Possible solution https://godbolt.org/z/EW13E14dv